# Tire pressure and its effects

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

My textbook reads as follows:-

"Tire pressure is important for the safety and
durability of automobile tires. Too low a pressure causes large deflections and the tire may
overheat; too high a pressure leads to excessive wear in the centre."

How does lower tire pressure lead to overheating of the tire and higher tire effect lead to excessive wear and tear?

Comment: A hint: the lower the pressure, the higher the surface area between tire and ground.

Comment: This video explains the rolling resistance of pneumatic tires. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_S2lyaMgBQ8 TLDR: Skip ahead to 2:30 if you don't want to learn all about the material properties of rubber.

Comment: Yes, clarified a couple of my doubts. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 3):

AT low pressure, the tire is almost flat, and each time it revolves the tread and sidewalls undergo significant flexure. Because rubber has internal friction, that flexure causes the rubber to heat up- and eventually get hot enough to destroy the tire.

When the tire is overinflated, its tread bulges out so much that the only part of the tread actually in contact with the pavement is a little patch in the very center of the tread. Since that little patch provides all the friction to propel, steer, and brake the car, it wears down rapidly.

This is  particular problem for high-performance motorcycle tires, which have an almost completely round cross section so the bike can be leaned way over in a sharp turn and still grip the road. This means that when traveling in a straight line, the center of the tire gets ground off quickly. For this reason, the center of the tire contains a harder rubber compound which resists wear, while the sidewalls are made from softer rubber which wears faster but grips much better. The best tires are *triple-compound*, with 3 different rubber hardnesses to them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!